# Can you tell TeXShop to compile a certain way without using a shebang?

Tags: compiling, texshop, automation

I have a custom class that has a bibliography option.  If I am not using that option, I would prefer to compile with `pdflatex`; if I am using that option, however, I would like to use `pdflatexmk`.  This is because `pdflatexmk` takes considerably longer to compile, which I do not want unless I need it.

The problem is, I do believe the shebang needs to be at the top of the file, as this:

```
\newif\ifbib\bibfalse
\DeclareOption{bib}{\bibtrue}

\ifbib
    % !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\else
    % !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\fi
```

does not work.  How might I be able to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this in the way you are trying. The magic comment lines are parsed by the editor; they have no connection to any of the TeX code in the document.  It's not clear why you need to do what you're doing anyway.  `latexmk` is usually smart enough not to do multiple runs when they're not needed. What I do when I'm drafting a document is simply use the non-`latexmk` version until I near the end and then change to using `latexmk`. This far less work than setting an option in the code; you simply take off or add the `mk` part to the magic command as needed.

If you really think you need to have more control over the build process, you could also use the `arara` TeXShop engine.

Answer (score 3):

Use the directive for pdflatexmk in the file. Use Cmd-T to typeset with pdflatexmk and Shift-Cmd-L (which overrides the directive and uses the Typeset Menu’s LaTeX command) to use pdflatex.

Comment: That's a cute trick. It won't work for documents using different engines, but still useful to know.

Comment: @AlanMunn : It is handiest if you need to run bibtex or makeindex but don't want to use the latexmk based engines at that time. However, I admit I use your solution in the case given.